# Hover placement issue

Tags: css

I am trying to create a box - in this case I've called it #rollover in the CSS & HTML -  that has four images on the left side.  When the end user rolls over each image on the left a larger version of the image appears to the right.  The problem I am having is keeping the larger image on the right within the #rollover div.

**CSS**

```
#rollover{
width:739px;
height: 600px;
border: 3px solid;
padding-top:10px;
padding-left: 40px;
padding-bottom:10px;
float:left;}

.picture {
width:150px; 
height: 150px;}

.picture a.small, .picture a.small:visited { 
display:block;  
text-decoration:none; 
background:#ffffff; 
top:0; 
left:0; 
border:0;}

.picture a img {
border:0;}

.picture a.small:hover {
text-decoration:none; 
background-color:#000000; 
color:#000000;}

.picture a .large {
display:block;  
width:0; 
height:0; 
border:0; 
top:0; 
left:0;}

.picture a.small:hover .large {  
position:absolute;
top:0;
width:550px; 
height:550px; 
left:160px;} 

body{
margin:0;}

#main{
width:800px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;}

#mast{
width:799px;
height:300px;
margin-top: 10px;
padding-top: 5px;
background-image: url(IFhalllogo.png);
background-repeat:no-repeat;}

#insidewrap{
width:749px;
margin:0;
padding:0;
border: 3px solid;
float:left;
border-color: #39C;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="rollover">
<div class="picture">
<a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="op/01-thumb.jpg"  title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="op/01-large.jpg" title="large image" /></a>
</div>
<div class="picture">
<a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="op/02-thumb.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="op/02-large.jpg" title="large image" /></a>
</div>
<div class="picture">
<a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="op/03-thumb.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="op/03-large.jpg" title="large image" /></a>
</div>
<div class="picture">
<a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image"><img src="op/04-thumb.jpg" title="small image" />
<img class="large" src="op/04-large.jpg" title="large image" /></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your CSS says it should be `50px` from the left margin: `.picture a.small:hover .large { position: relative; left:50px; }`. Shouldn't it be at least `150px`?

Comment: Try `position: absolute; top: 0`, and make sure `#rollover` is tall enough to accomodate the tallest image.

Comment: Seems to be working to me, at least on the y-axis: http://jsfiddle.net/Vbnjj/

Comment: Just add `position: relative;` to `#rollover`, and the absolute position elements inside will be positioned relative to it.

Comment: That seems to have worked!  I'm going to try to stamp this into another page and double check, but I think you've solved this for me.  Thanks so much!

Comment: That's great.  Tried it on other pages.  I'll remember in the future to set the main holding div to relative.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute positioning on the hover event.

Here is the code, fiddle around with the top and left attributes to get it where you want.

Hope this helps.

**CSS:**

```
#rollover{
    width:739px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 3px solid;
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
    float:left;
}

.picture {
    width:150px; 
    height: 150px;
}

.picture a.small, .picture a.small:visited { 
    display:block;  
    text-decoration:none; 
    background:#ffffff; 
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    border:0;
}

.picture a img {
    border:0;
}

.picture a.small:hover {
    text-decoration:none; 
    background-color:#000000; 
    color:#000000;
}

.picture a .large {
    display:block;  
    visibility:hidden;
}

.picture a.small:hover .large {
    display:block; 
    visibility: visible;
    position:absolute; 
    width:550px; 
    height:550px; 
    top:25px;
    left:220px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="rollover">
    <div class="picture">
        <a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image">
            <img src="op/01-thumb.jpg"  title="small image" />
            <img class="large" src="op/01-large.jpg" title="large image" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="picture">
        <a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image">
            <img src="op/02-thumb.jpg" title="small image" />
            <img class="large" src="op/02-large.jpg" title="large image" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="picture">
        <a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image">
            <img src="op/03-thumb.jpg" title="small image" />
            <img class="large" src="op/03-large.jpg" title="large image" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="picture">
        <a class="small" href="#nogo" title="small image">
            <img src="op/04-thumb.jpg" title="small image" />
            <img class="large" src="op/04-large.jpg" title="large image" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Had good luck bfavaretto above and everything is working well. I appreciate the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

Just to document: the solution here was to use `position: absolute` on the full size images, taking care to relative-position the container to make sure the images where positioned relative to that element:

```css
#rollover{
    position: relative;
    /* ... */
}

.picture a.small:hover .large {  
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:160px;
    /* ... */
}
```